# How do I have a user interrupt a countdown and restart the process?

Tags: c#

I am simulating a machine reading a Heart Beat. If the "user's" heart rate is within the accepted range, the app will sleep for 5 seconds then read again.

If the "user's" heart rate is outside the range then a countdown begins, leading to an end message.

I would like to be able to have a user interrupt the automatic countdown and restart the process

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Random_pulse
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int j = 1;
            int timeRemaining=10;

            do
            {
                int pulse = rnd.Next(0, 200);
                Console.WriteLine(pulse);

                if (pulse > 50 && pulse <= 190)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }

                else if (pulse <= 50 && pulse > 0 || pulse > 190)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine(timeRemaining--);
                        Console.Beep();
                        if (timeRemaining == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Alert sent!!");
                            j = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Alert sent!!");
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
            while (j>0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have the main thread sleep you could use a [`System.Timers.timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then use the main thread to start and stop the timer with input from the user.

Here's an example of the syntax.  This is a timer that elapses continuously every 1 sec.  `OnTimedEvent` would be your method of what you want to do.

```
 System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000)();
 timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

 timer.Start();
```

If you need to pass arguments to your method you will need to use a [lamda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).  For example:

```
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(() => OnTimedEvent(arg1,arg2));
```

So your OnTimedEvent method may look like this:

```
private void OnTimedEvent()
{

            int pulse = rnd.Next(0, 200);
            Console.WriteLine(pulse);

            if (pulse > 50 && pulse <= 190)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            else if (pulse <= 50 && pulse > 0 || pulse > 190)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine(timeRemaining--);
                    Console.Beep();
                    if (timeRemaining == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Alert sent!!");
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Alert sent!!");
                j = 0;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `timer` to countdown. And set the input key to restart the timer or process you want. Thread sleeping is not the way to perform countdown.

You can use `keydown` event, and can reset the `timer` in that event.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your solution simple, I'd suggest that you use a flag, say IsCancelled, which can be set by the user. After each 1 second interval, read the flag to check if the user has requested cancellation and break out of the for loop if the flag is true. Since your time interval is just 1 second, this might be an acceptable solution.

However, if you want true asynchrony, you can create a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for sending alerts and cancel them using the [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. In fact, the example on the msdn link is pretty close to what your are doing.
If you use a Task object, you'd have to 'Wait' on the task to get completed/cancelled in your 'else if' condition before continuing with the while loop. Seems to be a much complex solution for your problem. But this is a very interesting challenge and you'd learn a lot about asynchronous programming in C#.